# ModernCV - Errors Moderncvstyle{classic}

Tags: moderncv

I'm a begginer in this big world of LateX, I started to compose a curriculum using the `modercv` script. Generating the PDF I receive errors only if 
I upload the Moderncvstyle `classic`. With the default style `casual` the script seems without any error.
What is wrong?

Thank you for the help

Here the code

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2015 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
\moderncvcolor{black}                               % color options 'black', 'blue' (default), 'burgundy', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple' and 'red'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{Gia}{Pet}
%\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{Street}{Small town}{Italy}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+xxxxxx}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
%\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{luck3@gmail.com}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\social[linkedin]{www.linkedin.com/in/XXXX/}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
% \extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
\section{Experience}

\cventry{Mar.2016--Present}{Yep}{XXXX}{XXXXXXX}{}{Provide happiness. \newline{}%
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}%
\item Discuss;
\item Redact 
 % \begin{itemize}%
 % \item Sub-achievement (a);
 % \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
  %  \begin{itemize}
  %  \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
   % \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
   % \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    %\end{itemize}
 % \item Sub-achievement (c);
 % \end{itemize}
%\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{Jun.2013--Gen.2014}{XXX}{XXXX}{Kilimangiaro}{}{Manage initiatives}

%\subsection{Miscellaneous}Actively participant and team member in strategy, design, creative process and execution of initiatives
%\newline{}Actively participant and team member in strategy, design, creative process and execution of initiatives}
%\subsection{Miscellaneous}
%\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}
\cventry{Sep.2011--Mar.2012}{XX}{XXX}{XXXX}{}{Development and testing}

%\newline{} update in case more details are needed}
\cventry{Apr.2009--Mar.2009}{XXXX}{XXX}{XXX}{}{Design }


\section{Education}

\cventry{Oct.2010--Sept.2012}{XXX}{XXX}{XXX}{}{True cost } % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{Sept.2006--Oct.2010}{XXXX}{XXX}{XXX}{}{XXXX}
\cventry{Feb.2013}{XXX}{XXX}{XXX}{}{WLF}

%\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
%\section{Master thesis}
%\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
%\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
%\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}
 % \begin{itemize}%
 % \item Sub-achievement (a);
 % \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
  %  \begin{itemize}
  %  \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
   % \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
   % \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    %\end{itemize}
 % \item Sub-achievement (c);
 % \end{itemize}
%\item Achievement 3.

\pagebreak

\section{Personal Skills}

\textbf{Work related skills}%
\begin{itemize}
\item Great attitude on Problem-solving providing solution for customers
\item Analysis capability
\item Self-organized and attentive to details
\item Fast learning and focused on growth in order to give the best support and help to customers and colleagues
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Organisational/managerial skills}%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Aptitude to work in  a team
\item Used to work with deadlines and presentations 
\item Efficient organisation of workload, well organise and proactive
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Communication skills}%
\begin{itemize}
\item Good communication skills gained through my experience as Technical Sales Support position
\item Hold technical training  for  sales and  service departments
\item International work environment contributed multi-aspect approach and flexibility
\end{itemize}

\section{Languages}
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|r|}
%\hline
%\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{}\\
%\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{\Large English}}\\
%\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Reading}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Writing}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Speaking}}\\
\hline
\hspace{0.5cm} \textbf{Italian} \hspace{0.5cm} & \hspace{0.5cm}Mother tongue \hspace{0.5cm} & \hspace{0.5cm} Mother tongue \hspace{0.5cm} & \hspace{0.5cm}Mother tongue \hspace{0.5cm}\\
\hline
\hspace{0.5cm} \textbf{English} \hspace{0.5cm} & \hspace{0.5cm}Professional \hspace{0.5cm} & \hspace{0.5cm} Professional \hspace{0.5cm} & \hspace{0.5cm}Professional \hspace{0.5cm}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

%\cvitemwithcomment{Italian}{Mother tongue}{Comment}
%\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
%\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\begin{itemize}
\item{ Good command of office suite (Access, Excel, Word )}
\item{  Basic command of SQL and Visual Basic}
\item {  Origin for data analysis}
\end{itemize}


%\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
%\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
%\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

%\section{Interests}
%\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
%\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
%\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

%\section{Extra 1}
%\cvlistitem{Item 1}
%\cvlistitem{Item 2}
%\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation when the line wraps?}

%\section{Extra 2}
%\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
%\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
%\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

%\section{References}
%\begin{cvcolumns}
 % \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
 % \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
 % \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
%\end{cvcolumns}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% CONSIDER MERGING WITH PREAMBLE PART
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{May 13, 2018}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra 

%Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

%\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                              % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Here below the screen shot of the errors that I received.

[image]

## EDIT:

Resulting file list:

```
*File List*
moderncv.cls    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document c
lass
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
colortbl.sty    2018/05/02 v1.0c Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2018/04/30 v2.4h Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
fancyhdr.sty    2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2018-04-30 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2018-04-30 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2018-04-30 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2018-04-30 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
microtype.sty    2018/01/14 v2.7a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2018/01/14 v2.7a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2018/01/14 v2.7a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and lett
er compatibility patches
moderncvstyleclassic.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r style scheme: classic
moderncviconsmarvosym.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and lett
er icons: marvosym
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
moderncvheadi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter heade
r variant: 1
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
moderncvbodyi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter body 
variant: 1
    umvs.fd
moderncvcolorblack.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter 
color scheme: black
inputenc.sty    2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
geometry.sty    2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
geometry.cfg
hyperref.sty    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (
RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
"Prova XXXX".out
"Prova XXXX".out
  mt-mvs.cfg    2006/07/05 v1.1 microtype config. file: Marvosym Euro (RS)
 ***********
```

Here below the message that I receveid. Please advise if you need more information.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size <34> not available
(Font) size <35.83> substituted on input line 117.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname
\ \@lastname
l.117 \end{minipage}}
%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname \ \@lastname
l.117 \end{minipage}}
%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.120 \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}
%
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 120--135
[]
)
(C:\Users\Tiag\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\moderncv\moderncvbodyi.sty
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvbodyi',
but the package provides `moderncvbodyi'.
Package: moderncvbodyi 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter bod
y variant: 1
\hintscolumnwidth=\skip72
\separatorcolumnwidth=\skip73
\maincolumnwidth=\skip74
\doubleitemcolumnwidth=\skip75
\listitemsymbolwidth=\skip76
LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for U+mvs on input line 46.
(C:\Users\Tiag\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\marvosym\umvs.fd)
\listitemcolumnwidth=\skip77
\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth=\skip78
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
.
. Redefining command \photo with sig. 'O{\hintscolumnwidth -0.8pt-2\fboxsep
. }O{0.4pt}m' on line 51.
.................................................
\baseletterheight=\skip79
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
.
. Redefining command \section with sig. 'sm' on line 73.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
.
. Redefining command \subsection with sig. 'sm' on line 80.
.................................................
\cvitemwithcommentbox=\box57
\cvitemwithcommentskilllength=\skip80
\cvitemwithcommentcommentlength=\skip81
))
(C:\Users\Tiag\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\moderncv\moderncvcolorblack
.sty
Package: moderncvcolorblack 2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and lette
r color scheme: black
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks30
\inpenc@posthook=\toks31
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\geometry\geometry.sty"
Package: geometry 2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
```

Comment: I copied the LOG FILE, it seems the last version

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` as first line in your TeX code, compile three times and chack the log file. At the end of it you will find a list of used packages and versions for your code. Please add this list to your question!

Comment: Please add new informations by editing your question, do not edit answers. Please add the complete first error message from  the log file to your question. Or can you give a link to your complete `log` file ...

Comment: I was sure that I answered to you. Anyway I didn't understand why the classic style doesn't work, I'm using the casual style to avoid the issue. Any new advise?

Comment: OK, I uploaded the log file on We Transfer --> https://we.tl/7kHAwBmCFk

Answer (score 1):

Too long for an comment:

the resulting list of used packages and version numbers on my computer is:

```
 *File List*
moderncv.cls    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
colortbl.sty    2018/05/02 v1.0c Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2018/04/30 v2.4h Tabular extension package (FMi)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
fancyhdr.sty    2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footers
tweaklist.sty    
    calc.sty    2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2018-05-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2018-05-13 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2018-05-13 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2018-05-13 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
microtype.sty    2018/01/14 v2.7a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
microtype-pdftex.def    2018/01/14 v2.7a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2018/01/14 v2.7a microtype main configuration file (RS)
moderncvcollection.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 moderncv collections
moderncvcompatibility.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter compatibility patches
moderncvstyleclassic.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter style scheme: classic
moderncviconsmarvosym.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter icons: marvosym
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
moderncvheadi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter header variant: 1
moderncvbodyi.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter body variant: 1
    umvs.fd
moderncvcolorblack.sty    2015/07/28 v2.0.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter color scheme: black
inputenc.sty    2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
geometry.sty    2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
geometry.cfg
hyperref.sty    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
   puenc.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
   t1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
  mt-cmr.cfg    2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (RS)
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
  433597.out
  433597.out
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  mt-mvs.cfg    2006/07/05 v1.1 microtype config. file: Marvosym Euro (RS)
```

Please check this list with yours at the end of your `mwe.log` file (if `mwe.tex` is the name of your tex code file).

Please see that you get this list only if you have

```
\listfiles % <====================================================
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
```

at the beginning of your TeX code ....

On my system your code gives only one error message because I do not have your used `*.bib` file ...

## EDIT:

You have an older version of the following packages on your system.

```
  xparse.sty    2018-04-30 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2018-04-30 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2018-04-30 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2018-04-30 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
```

Please update your tex distribution!